# Instance defined under child class returning nil and RSpec: no implicit conversion from nil to integer

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have below code where action class is being returned after require

**Robot Class**

```
attr_accessor :action

    def initialize 
        @action = Actions.new
    end

    def left
        @action.left
    end
```

Now Action class uses `Direction::Move.new` instance which is defined under initialize method.

**Actions Class**

```
def place(x_coordinate, y_coordinate, direction = :north)
        @x_coordinate = x_coordinate
        @y_coordinate = y_coordinate
        @direction = direction
        @report.log_position(x_coordinate, y_coordinate, direction) if

        x_coordinate.between?(@board.left_limit, @board.right_limit) && 
        y_coordinate.between?(@board.bottom_limit, @board.top_limit) &&
        @move.directions.grep(direction).present?
    end

    def left
        @move.left(direction)
    end
```

I have now defined Actions class with place method so direction gets allocated to `attr_accessor` then `robot.left` is called

```
describe '#left' do
        it 'should turn left' do
            action.place(0, 0, Direction::North)
            expect(robot.left).to eq(Direction::West)
        end
    end
```

But when I do Rspec test, it returns below error:

```
RSpec: no implicit conversion from nil to integer
```

Why `robot.left` which is calling `action.left` doesn't allow `direction` to be passed over to this `action.left` method?

Comment: What line is that error occurring on?

Comment: Error occurs on Failure/Error: expect(robot.left).to eq(Direction::West)

Comment: No, in your implementation.

Comment: Error is from @move.left(direction) on Actions class where direction is nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward explanation I can think of is that the `action` variable referenced in your example refers to an instance of `Actions` other than the one created by `robot`.  If you create a `Robot` and don't call `place` on the associated instance of `Actions`, then when `robot.left` calls `@action.left`, `@direction` will be undefined in that `Actions` instance, so the accessor `direction` will return `nil`, which results in the error.

Can you share the remainder of your `spec` file related to how `robot` and `action` are defined?

Comment: I think it's due to attr_accessor :board, :x_coordinate, :y_coordinate, :direction in Actions Class where direction is being allocated under attr_accessor

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've ended up placing same place method under Robot class then called this method in spec file instead of calling from action. This ended up working fine as the variables are passed through

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. You still might want to post your original code so that others can learn from this. Variable assignment issues with `describe`, `let` and `before` are fairly common in `rspec` and it helps to see concrete examples.